# Python / DRF - error when trying to serialize a dictionary

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have the following dictionary:

```
<type 'dict'>: {u'user2': {'username': u'user2', 'problems_attempts_last_week': None, 'videos_last_week': None, 'correct_problems_last_week': None, 'videos_overall': None, 'problems_overall': None, 'problems_attempts_overall': None, 'correct_problems_overall': None, 'forum_posts_last_week': 2, 'forum_posts_overall': 13, 'date_last_active': datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 23, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'problems_last_week': None}, 
u'user3': {'username': u'user3', 'problems_attempts_last_week': None, 'videos_last_week': None, 'correct_problems_last_week': 6, 'videos_overall': None, 'problems_overall': 18, 'problems_attempts_overall': 3, 'correct_problems_overall': 15, 'forum_posts_last_week': None, 'forum_posts_overall': None, 'date_last_active': datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 23, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'problems_last_week': 6}, 
u'user1': {'username': u'user1', 'problems_attempts_last_week': 4, 'videos_last_week': 1, 'correct_problems_last_week': None, 'videos_overall': 3, 'problems_overall': 8, 'problems_attempts_overall': 4, 'correct_problems_overall': 4, 'forum_posts_last_week': 2, 'forum_posts_overall': 2, 'date_last_active': datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 23, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'problems_last_week': 4}}
```

And the following Serializer for it:

```
class UserEngagementSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    """
    Serializes row data
    """
    username = serializers.CharField()
    videos_overall = serializers.IntegerField()
    videos_last_week = serializers.IntegerField()
    problems_overall = serializers.IntegerField()
    problems_last_week = serializers.IntegerField()
    correct_problems_overall = serializers.IntegerField()
    correct_problems_last_week = serializers.IntegerField()
    problems_attempts_overall = serializers.IntegerField()
    problems_attempts_last_week = serializers.IntegerField()
    forum_posts_overall = serializers.IntegerField()
    forum_posts_last_week = serializers.IntegerField()
    date_last_active = serializers.DateTimeField(format=settings.DATE_FORMAT)
```

When I try to return the results from my REST service, the following error is displayed:

> AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for
>   field `username` on serializer `UserEngagementSerializer`. The
>   serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any
>   attribute or key on the `unicode` instance. Original exception text
>   was: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'username'.

This serializer worked when I was returning a straight Django queryset. How do I make it work with the dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend you to upgrade to python3

```
serializer = UserEngagementSerializer(u['user2'])
print(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because Python treats the 'username' value as unicode. This is probably caused by the source you are retrieving the data from. You'll need to make sure to encode the value of the key 'username' to UTF-8 or ASCII before passing the dictionary to the serializer using:

```
dict["username"].encode("utf-8")
```